# about full text query in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have a nvarchar column which contains English and Japanese text. I want to make full text search on this column. When configure full text search, we need to specify language option for word breaker (e.g. using English work breaker or using Japanese word breaker). I am wondering in this case, what language should I assign? I am not sure if Japanese language work breaker works for English as well.

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Would it not be better (if possible) to separate the English and Japanese text in to separate columns? Then you can apply a text search to each one.

Comment: Does it mean for each row, either English column or Japanese column is empty? In my application, the column to be searched is either in Japanese or in English. So, for each column, I need to create two additional columns, column in English and column in Japanese. :-)

Comment: But you can also delete the original column, so only one extra column. Seems like a good solution?

Comment: If only use one column -- you mean store Japanese in the specific column for the row in Japanese and store English in the specific column for the row in English, then which language work breaker should I use to meet with the needs of the same column for different languges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose the neutral-word-breaker if you have a column that has different language (especially western and non-western languages together) in it.

There are some other options such as

- Seperating the columns by each language (as @Tony stated)
- if your data is a plain text; converting it to the xml data type and add language tags that indicate the language which is used by the full text engine.
- developing a custom word breaker (Although it is not a optimal solution)

Here is an [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142507%28SQL.100%29.aspx) about best practices for choosing a language when creating a Full-Text index.

**Added After Comments**

It can be queried multiple columns in many ways depending on your use case. The easiest way is using the CONTAINS predicate to query multiple columns by specifying a list of columns to search as shown below;

```
SELECT Name, Color FROM Production.Product
WHERE CONTAINS((Name, Color), 'Red');
```

Another solution may be using a language indicator column that can be used in the CASE/IF statements which helps you conditionally split the query by language. You can also use the DATALENGTH() TSQL function to check whether it is empty and decide which column to choose.

Comment: Thanks orka! How to achieve better work breaking and more accurate full text search performance? Using neutral work breaker or using separate column for different languages?

Comment: I think it would be better if you separate columns by languages for the sake of accurate results and performance.

Comment: Thanks orka, if I separate columns by language, for example, an English column and a Japanese column. And I will use English word breaker on the English column and using Japanese word breaker on the Japanese column. So, either English or Japanese column is empty since a row is in a specific language, can not be in two languages (e.g. Japanese row has an empty English column). But my query condition is, return any matched rows either English or Japanese column matches input query. I do not know how to write such kinds of a full text query, any ideas?